# Confidence intervals for a ratio of a log-normally distributed variable and a regression estimator

Tags: confidence-interval, regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression

I am studying returns on advertising, here defined as **[Customer LifeTime Value]/[Customer Acquisition Cost]**. I have obtained values and respective CIs for both variables and now i have to combine them to form a ratio and its CIs.

Customer lifetime value is an average of 10k+ observations and it is a **log-normally distributed variable**.

The average Customer acquisition cost is obtained from a GAM regression where 'ad spend' explains changes in Signup volumes. The reciprocal of the **regression coefficient** 'ad spend' represents Customer acquisition cost. (The GAM regression is as follows: signups = ad spend + 's(controls)', family=nb())

Any ideas of how to obtain the **CIs for the ratio?** Afaik The EC Fieller method requires the variables to be normally distributed